# How to specify gdb source path

Tags: gdb

I want to inspect reload1.cc in gdb (please ignore the parent dir is /root. I am using docker to prepare the environment).

```
# cd /root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/newlib/libc/stdlib
# gdb --args m32c-elf-cc -B/root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/m32c_build/m32c-elf/newlib/ -isystem /root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/m32c_build/m32c-elf/newlib/targ-include -isystem /root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/newlib/libc/include -B/root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/m32c_build/m32c-elf/libgloss/m32c -L/root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/m32c_build/m32c-elf/libgloss/libnosys -L/root/r8c/newlib-4.1.0/libgloss/m32c    -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"newlib\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"newlib\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"4.1.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"newlib\ 4.1.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -I. -I../../../../../newlib/libc/stdlib -Os -fno-builtin -DPREFER_SIZE_OVER_SPEED -DSMALL_MEMORY -DMISSING_SYSCALL_NAMES -DABORT_PROVIDED -DHAVE_INIT_FINI      -g -O2 -c -o lib_a-ldtoa.o ldtoa.c

(gdb) list reload1.cc:1
No source file named reload1.cc.
(gdb) dir /root/r8c/gcc-12.2.0/gcc
Source directories searched: /root/r8c/gcc-12.2.0/gcc:$cdir:$cwd
(gdb) list reload1.cc:1
No source file named reload1.cc.
(gdb)
quit

# ls /root/r8c/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/reload1.cc
/root/r8c/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/reload1.cc

# gdb --version
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Why gdb cannot detect reload1.cc?
Added info: The readelf does not show reload1.cc.

```
# readelf -wl $(which m32c-elf-cc) | grep reload1
```

The build log shows reload1.cc is compiled with -g3.

```
#8 294.8 g++  -fno-PIE -c   -g3     -DIN_GCC  -DCROSS_DIRECTORY_STRUCTURE   -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wmissing-format-attribute -Woverloaded-virtual -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I../../gcc -I../../gcc/. -I../../gcc/../include -I../../gcc/../libcpp/include -I../../gcc/../libcody  -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libdecnumber/dpd -I../libdecnumber -I../../gcc/../libbacktrace  -g3 -o reload1.o -MT reload1.o -MMD -MP -MF ./.deps/reload1.TPo ../../gcc/reload1.cc
```

Comment: If you run `readelf -wl m32c-elf-cc`, does `reload1.cc` appear in the File Name Table?

Comment: No. But according to the build log, -g3 is specified while compliing reload1.cc.